Azure Data Factory issue
i Have recently given a Data engineering interview. In that interviwer asked  me a question on ADF where i faced a issue while responding to it.  Your help would be helpful here.

there is a emp table on prem sql server db
feilds : emp table -> emp_id, emp_name, dept_id

there a csv file in blob storage
dept.csv -> dept_id,dept-name

we need to create a target table in azure db
emp_details - > dept_name, total_emp_count


here we can only use ADF pipeline in order to complete this scenario.
Appropiate answer based on the given scenario

Could you please provide your approach if you tried anything?

Yes, So for the first case that is. populating data from on prem sql server i said we can use copy data activity in order to move data via pipeline.
But for 2nd casei am not very sure on the approachthat we need here.

why don't you copy both emp table and dept.csv to Azure sql table using copy activity in ADF and use sql script to create target table using both tables?

Actually, The interviwer ask was that we need to perforrm everything using ADF in order to acheive the target scenario with a new table db emp_details with only 2 columns dept_name, total_emp_count.

We can't direclty query any csv file from blob storage within ADF. We need to use  some  activity in order to synchronise both source an then we can eventually acheive the final output.

I said that copy csv file and on-premises sql table to Azure sql table , after that you will be able to query it.

You can follow below approach to achieve your requirement:
Copy your emp table to csv file from on-premises to blob storage using ADF copy activity. Use data flow to join above two files to get in required format as follows:
Create two datasets with two csv files dept.csv and emp table.csv, use them as source dataset, add Join transformation to them. Use  dept_id  as key column, configure Join transformation as shown below:

Add aggregate transformation to the Join transformation in the Group By field, add dept_name  and total_emp_count as aggregate column with function count(emp_id) as shown below:

You will get the required format of table as shown below:

Add Azure SQL dataset as sink, debug the pipeline with dataflow activity with created dataflow, then you will get the target table in Azure SQL database.

Thanks for sharing this information.!! Appreciated
